# Do Salesforce DX scratch orgs allow a namespace to be nominated?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

I see that the [Salesforce DX](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/products/salesforce-dx/) pilot program has finished; is there a way to take a look at Salesforce DX now (June 2017)?

(Also see [What is Salesforce DX?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146123/what-is-salesforce-dx) on this forum.)

My specific question... We've had problems lately with namespace related bugs in our managed packages. We do our development in non-namespace orgs and namespace bugs have leaked into our managed packages (e.g. Visualforce page name-based logic breaking when the namespace prefix is present). Do the **scratch orgs that are part of Salesforce DX allow a namespace to be nominated** so they can simulate the packaging org in the sense that developers can fully test their code with a namespace present in a scratch org?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You specify the namespace in the scratch-org's configuration file when using the org creation command. You must first associate the packaging org with your Environment Hub Org before you can use the namespace parameter, and the namespace must match the namespace prefix in the packaging org. I can't share specific details, but the answer is, yes, you will be able to use namespaces in your scratch orgs, which will ease spinning up new orgs and deploying changes to your packaging org.

Comment: Public beta is expected to go live on 28 June, 2017. There will be instructions for how to enable the dev hub org in one of your orgs, along with an alternative to sign up for a dev hub trial org if you want to trial before you turn it on.